# Export Contact List in Outlook 2010 to a pst file

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010, contacts

How do I export the contact list from Outlook 2010 to a PST file?

Answer (score 1):

Illustrated steps in Outlook 2007:

Choose import/export...

[image: Import/Export]

Export to a file...

[image]

Choose PST as target file type...

[image]

Choose your Contacts folder (note option to Include subfolders)

[image]

Browse or enter a location/name for output file and Finish!

[image]